# How to display the pivot value in multi select2 in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

How to display the pivot value in multi select2 in Laravel?

In my controller

```
$appointment = Appointment::with('services')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

This is the output

[image]

In my blade, I want to display the pivot table value **service_id** in multi select2. Currently I have two records in my pivot

[image]
this my blade

```
@foreach ($service as $item)
     <option value="{{ $item->id }}"
        {{ in_array($item->id, $appointment->pivot_should_be_here ?: []) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $item->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your controller, you have to convert this values into Array, and then you can pass this to your blade.

```
$appointment = Appointment::with('services')->where('id', $id)->first();
$app = $appointment->services->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Then in your blade

```
@foreach ($service as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->id }}"
        {{ in_array($item->id, $app ?: []) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $item->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```